# XSLT Copy limited by attribute value pair

Tags: xml, xslt, copy, transformation

I am trying to copy a couple of children from an XML file into another XML file.   I created a whitelist which works for the named elements, but I can not find a match when I try to limit a single attribute name value pair which is also a child.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog catalog-id="Primary">
    <product product-id="COLAKIT">
        <ean/>
        <upc/>
        <unit>SKU</unit>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="Base_Color">Brown</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="Shipping_Cost">0.0</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="showEstimatedDelivery">false</custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>
        <classification-category>Kitchen_Housewares-Coffee_and_Tea</classification-category>
    </product>

    <product product-id="COLONIAL-48-M-K">
        <ean/>
        <upc/>
        <unit>SKU</unit>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="Base_Color">Coffee</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="Shipping_Cost">0.0</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="showEstimatedDelivery">false</custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>
        <classification-category>Outdoor_Living-Heaters-Fireplaces</classification-category>
    </product>

</catalog>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="some:ns">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <ns:WhiteList>
  <name>classification-category</name>
  <name>custom-attribute[attribute-id()='Shipping_Cost']</name>
 </ns:WhiteList>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant-or-self::*[name()=document('')/*/ns:WhiteList/*])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also, the primary XML has 100s of nodes and I only want 3 which is why am I trying to white list instead of exclude.  Please let me know what I am missing with the attribute=value match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, of course the attempt you're using above doesn't work, since your source document doesn't have any elements with the name `custom-attribute[attribute-id()='Shipping_Cost']` (also, there is no XPath function with the name `attribute-id()`).

Standard XSLT 1.0 doesn't have the ability to evaluate XPaths from string values that are present in the XML, and so I think you may need to take an approach that's somewhat less generic than you would like it to be. Here is one such approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="some:ns">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <ns:WhiteList>
  <element>classification-category</element>
  <attributeId>Shipping_Cost</attributeId>
 </ns:WhiteList>
 <xsl:variable name="whiteList" select="document('')/*/ns:WhiteList" />

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant-or-self::*[name()=$whiteList/element] or
                            (descendant-or-self::custom-attribute/@attribute-id = 
                             $whiteList/attributeId)
                           )]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you.   This worked great.  I appreciate the help.  Makes sense on the string XPath

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that `"custom-attribute[attribute-id()='Shipping_Cost']"` is not a **name**. It's not even (in your case) an XPath expression; it's a **string** - and you would need an extension function (or XSLT 3.0) to **evaluate** it as XPath. And you would have to change it in order to evaluate as **valid** XPath, i.e. use `@attribute-id` instead of `attribute-id()`.

The bigger problem with your approach is that it's very inefficient. In XSLT, it pays to be explicit, especially if you're talking about hundreds of nodes. Instead of constructing a "side-way" white list of names, consider a much more direct approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- "white list" -->
<xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@product-id"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="classification-category"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id='Shipping_Cost']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to handle a dynamic evaluation of sorts in XSLT 1.0, but it will involve doing two transformations. It takes advantage of the fact that XSLT is well-formed XML, which means you can transform it using XSLT into some other XSLT. A case of "XSLT write thyself".

The idea is your have a pre-processing step to transform your current XSLT to a new-improved version of XSLT including your 'dynamic' expressions, which you then apply to your XML:

You would start off by changing your current XSLT to this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="some:ns">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <ns:WhiteList>
  <name>classification-category</name>
  <name>custom-attribute[@attribute-id = 'Shipping_Cost']</name>
 </ns:WhiteList>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For the first 'pre-processing' step of the transform, you would have an XSLT that consisted of the identity template, but also a template that matched `xsl:styleheet` which copied it, but also added a new `xsl:template` instruction, whose `match` attribute was built up from the information your `ns:WhiteList`

Here is this pre-processing XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xslOut="xlst.temp" xmlns:ns="some:ns">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="xslOut" result-prefix="xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="/xsl:stylesheet">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

            <xslOut:template>
                <xsl:attribute name="match">
                    <xsl:text>*[</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns:WhiteList/name">
                        <xsl:if test="position() > 1"> and </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:text>not(descendant-or-self::</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xslOut:template>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns:WhiteList" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of `xsl:namespace-alias` which is used here to literally output xslt elements (If you tried to replace `<xslOut:template>` with `<xsl:template>` that would cause an error.

When the pre-processing XSLT is applied to the initial XSLT, this amended XSLT is generated

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns="some:ns"
                version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant-or-self::classification-category) and not(descendant-or-self::custom-attribute[@attribute-id = 'Shipping_Cost'])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can then apply this generated XSLT to your XML, to output the following:

```
<catalog catalog-id="Primary">
   <product product-id="COLAKIT">
      <custom-attributes>
         <custom-attribute attribute-id="Shipping_Cost">0.0</custom-attribute>
      </custom-attributes>
      <classification-category>Kitchen_Housewares-Coffee_and_Tea</classification-category>
   </product>
   <product product-id="COLONIAL-48-M-K">
      <custom-attributes>
         <custom-attribute attribute-id="Shipping_Cost">0.0</custom-attribute>
      </custom-attributes>
      <classification-category>Outdoor_Living-Heaters-Fireplaces</classification-category>
   </product>
</catalog>
```